# WSO2 EMM emm-agent-android download

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have successefully installed WSO2 EMM.
Now, i want to download the emm-agent-android app.
I accessed from my adroid device to my_url:9443/emm -> Device management and i clicked on "Enroll a device" button.
I got this follewed url : my_url:9443/emm/api/device_enroll that i accessed from may device and i clicked on "Download Agent" button.
I got be then redirected to the url: http://my_url:9763/emm/client_app/emm-agent-android.apk web page not found
So I change the url to https://my_url:9443/emm/client_app/emm-agent-android.apk 
The download starts but with failure what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have logged to the EMM console using admin / tenant admin credentials for at-least once. If the everything works fine the address to download the agent should be something like "http://10.100.5.37:9763/emm/client_app/emm-agent-android.apk". Make sure you have the client app in "/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/client_app" folder. Try to invoke the download agent address directly from the browser without going through "https://my_url:9443/emm/api/device_enroll". You can not download the agent from "https" endpoint unless the SSL setup is configured properly.

Comment: I have checked that the emm-agent-android.apk is in "/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/client_app" but the url "http://my_ip:9763/emm/client_app/emm-agent-android.apk" not found <br>

So I checked listening ports <br> netstat | grep 9443 show lines but nestat|grep 9763 display nothing <br> Is there config file to edit

Comment: There is nothing to configure to bind to port 9763. Could you check for port binding issues in the carbon log when starting the EMM server? or you can simple check the carbon.log file in "/repository/logs" directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that the emm-agent-android.apk is in "/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/client_app" but the url "http://my_ip:9763/emm/client_app/emm-agent-android.apk" not found

So I checked listening ports 
 netstat | grep 9443 show lines but nestat|grep 9763 display nothing 
 Is there config file to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Device and the Server in the same network? (Unless your server is hosted in a proper host and it has a public IP which you can access from anywhere)

Comment: Thanks Kusun, the problem was resolved .It is due to a closed  port and the device and the server was not on the same network.